# Navigation in eww, following links, bookmarks

Tags: emacs24.4, eww

When the cursor in eww is over a link, how can I follow it? Right now I copy it with 'w', and run eww again, which is kind of cumbersome.

In the same venue, if I access the bookmarks with 'B', how can I follow it, without copying and pasting after running M-x eww?

Comment: Is using the mouse a valid option?

Comment: I'd prefer to use the keyboard. But I am also curious about how to use the mouse, since clicking on a link is also not working.

Comment: The snapshot developer GUI build of Emacs -- 25.1.50.1 -- works out of the box with eww and the mouse.  What version of Emacs and OS are you using?  It is bound to the function `shr-browse-url`, which you can use by placing the cursor on the link and evaluating that function -- i.e., `M-x eval-expression RET (shr-browse-url) RET`  It is also interactive, so you could type `M-x shr-browse-url`

Comment: Yes, clicking is working. The connection was slow and I rushed to the conclusion that it was not. For bookmarks I have to Ctrl+click, but that's OK. Is the keyboard navigation supported?

Comment: The `eww-link-keymap` shows that the return key is bound to `eww-follow-link`, so try that when the cursor is on a link.  I don't use this library and have never played with bookmarks, so I'm not familiar with it.  In an eww buffer, type `M-x describe-mode RET` and read through the keybindings that are listed in the help buffer.

Comment: @lawlist: How did you find the eww-link-keymap thing, BTW? Is the only options looking directly into the eww.el package code?

Comment: Most libraries use the words `mode-map` in the source-code and `follow-link` is also fairly common.  I typed `M-x find-library RET eww RET` and then just used `isearch` for the two references above, some of which appear multiple times in that library.  The reference to `"\r"` in a `define-key` statement is one of the various ways to indicate the return key.  As you become more accustomed to looking at the `elisp` source-code, it is almost easier than reading the documentation to see what does what.  Other than `describe-mode` (mentioned above), there may be other ways to see all the keymaps.